Math problems amount to some learning? So how would I tackle alot of problems given a time interval?
I know taking a while to solving a problem matters and that I'd need to consider where I feel I'm lacking or lagging behind on a problem to know which to focus on.
But if I were to tackle conceptual and not just computational ones, how would I tackle alot of problems without being so overwhelmed. When I need to focus on one problem first, I feel too slow or overly focusing on a small thing that it could teach me. I fear I'd be spending too much time on a problem without much return instead of focusing on other stuff.
Additionally:
Some problems offer some amount of learning already, some people might say 'focusing on one problem offers alot of learning already', I just dont know if thats actually the case generally or not. I feel like I'd miss out or take too much time focusing on one problem and concept if thats the case?

Hello, it is difficult for me to understand your question. Could you add something concrete there? Maybe a concrete problem and where you are struggling with it.

Interesting question. Other than the structure your textbook gives, learning is a chaotic process. and trying to predict what will or will not help is practically impossible. But what will not help is wasting time asking questions like, "what can I do to help my maths?" Instead, just go and do some maths! All that said, you should try to get an overview (breadth is better than depth) of what you are learning before you dive in. Sometimes the problem with this is that it is difficult to gain breadth without some baseline level of understanding first.

I'm having difficulties understanding your question, but I believe you say that you're overwhelmed because of the fact that it takes you too much time to solve some questions, realising that you don't have enough time, making you panic, and reducing your motivation even more. Am I right?
When I was in school, at the beginning of every exam I have been told first to read all the questions and mark the ones I can answer directly. Those ones I solved immediately. After that, I started the ones for which I knew I needed some more time, but I was confident that I would be able to handle those.
Only completely at the end, I could start with the really difficult questions, and also there I needed to prioritise them: first the ones who I might solve and the ones who get me the maximum of the points.
I don't know if you have your problem during an exam or just at home, but the way of working applies on both situations.

Why the downvote?

down vote since it is not about math education.

@trula: are you kidding? My answer contains a strategy about how to deal with math exams, ever exams in general.

Sorry Dominique, i Did not see any down vote on your answer, so I spoke of the down vote for the question.
